# SQL Server does not exist or access denied but management studio connection works

Tags: sql-server, vb6

I am trying to log on to SQLServer express 2008R2 on a Windows 2003 server using Sql server authentication over a VPN.
The login and password work for Management Studio but not for the connection string in a VB6 program.

The connection string is of format

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=databasename;Data Source=ComputerIP\SQLEXPRESS;UID=usr;PWD=mypassword
```

where ComputerIP is the computer IP Address
How should I proceed to troubleshoot?

Comment: Instead of user id and password, what happens if you try using Intergrated security=SSPI?

Comment: The user is not on the domain, hence I am not using it.

Comment: In management studio do use IP or host name to connect to server?

Comment: Actually I use IP in both management studio and the connection string.